# Brightness of VAIO E series

Tags: sony-vaio, brightness

My VAIO E series 14P with windows 8 is having problem with the display brightness. It can't adjust at all. Even the display is the minimum but the display still in the brightest. Anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

- [Dimmer](http://www.nelsonpires.com/software/dimmer/)
- Go to you graphics card panel and adjust the brightness manually.

  I have a VAIO too and this is a common problem, not because of Windows, is because the screen is soo bright that the settings barely a work.